# Load Person Account Record type in Lightning Components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm having issues with my submit form in a lightning component. The form should create a person account, but it is default set to business account, but I can't figure out why. I got an apex class that returns the ID for Person Account (and the debug log actually shows that id), but the lightning component is just not fetching that data. See my code below:

```
    <aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes, force:hasRecordId"
                access="global"
                controller="CustomerInformationClass"
                extends="c:Base">


    <aura:registerEvent name="CustomerSubmit" type="c:CustomerSubmitForm" />

    <aura:attribute name="newAccount" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="simpleNewAccount" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="newAccountError" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="newAccountId" type="Id" access="private"  />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <force:recordData aura:id="accountRecordCreator"
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      targetRecord="{!v.newAccount}"
                      targetFields="{!v.simpleNewAccount}"
                      targetError="{!v.newAccountError}" />


    <!-- Display Lightning Data Service errors -->
    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.newAccountError))}">
        <div class="recordError">
            <ui:message title="Error" severity="error" closable="true">
                {!v.newAccountError}
            </ui:message>
        </div>
    </aura:if>

    <!-- Display the new contact form -->

    <lightning:card iconName="action:new_account" title="Create Account">
        <form class="slds-form—stacked" style="margin: 10px">
        <lightning:input aura:id="accountField" name="firstName" label="Last Name" value="{!v.simpleNewAccount.Name}" required="true"/>
        <lightning:input aura:id="accountField" name="title" label="Phone" value="{!v.simpleNewAccount.Phone}" />
        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-m-around_x-small">
            <lightning:button label="Save account" onclick="{!c.handleSaveAccount}" variant="brand" class="slds-m-top_medium"/>
        </div>
        </form>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
{{
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        // Prepare a new record from template
        helper.callServer(component, "c.getRecordTypeId", function(response) {
            component.set("v.newAccountId", response)
        });
        console.log(component.get("v.newAccountId") + "#### in Customer Information Controller ####");
        component.find("accountRecordCreator").getNewRecord(
            "Account", // sObject type (objectApiName)
            component.get("v.newAccountId"),      // recordTypeId
            false,     // skip cache?
            $A.getCallback(function() {
                var rec = component.get("v.newAccount");
                var error = component.get("v.newAccountError");
                if(error || (rec === null)) {
                    console.log("Error initializing record template: " + error);
                    return;
                }
                console.log("Record template initialized: " + rec.sobjectType);

            })
        );

    },

    handleSaveAccount: function(component, event, helper) {
            component.find("accountRecordCreator").saveRecord(function(saveResult) {
                if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
                    // record is saved successfully
                    var customerAccountId = saveResult.recordId; // Gets the record ID of the account created
                    var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:CustomerSubmitForm");
                            appEvent.setParams({
                                customerAccountId: customerAccountId // customerAccountId in the CustomerSubmitForm event is now set to the ID that was just created
                            });
                    appEvent.fire(); // Fires the event to store customerAccountId in the Event "CustomerSubmitForm.evt"
                    console.log(customerAccountId);
                    var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");

                    resultsToast.setParams({
                        "title": "Saved",
                        "message": "The record was saved."
                    });
                    resultsToast.fire();
                }
                else if (saveResult.state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                    // handle the incomplete state
                    console.log("User is offline, device doesn't support drafts.");
                }
                else if (saveResult.state === "ERROR") {
                    // handle the error state
                    console.log('Problem saving contact, error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Unknown problem, state: ' + saveResult.state + ', error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
                }
            });
    },
})
```

Apex class

```
public with sharing class CustomerInformationClass {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getRecordTypeId() {
        Id personAccountRecordId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Person Account').getRecordTypeId();
        System.debug(personAccountRecordId);
        return personAccountRecordId;
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? Why is a Person Account being created?

Appreciate all help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've made a classic mistake in JavaScript; you presumed that the value from getRecordTypeId would already be set in your init script. However, since the call is asynchronous, v.newAccountId is actually *null*, so it's using the default type for the user (presumably a Person Account Record Type). Put the getNewRecord call inside the callback:

```
// Prepare a new record from template
helper.callServer(component, "c.getRecordTypeId", $A.getCallback(function(response) {
    component.set("v.newAccountId", response);
    console.log(component.get("v.newAccountId") + "#### in Customer Information Controller ####");
    component.find("accountRecordCreator").getNewRecord(
        "Account", // sObject type (objectApiName)
        component.get("v.newAccountId"),      // recordTypeId
        false,     // skip cache?
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            var rec = component.get("v.newAccount");
            var error = component.get("v.newAccountError");
            if(error || (rec === null)) {
                console.log("Error initializing record template: " + error);
                return;
            }
            console.log("Record template initialized: " + rec.sobjectType);

        })
    );

}));
```